# Вопрос по декораторам и функциям js

Tags: javascript, функции, декоратор

В учебнике learnjs не могу понять как работает данный пример, почему после вызова функции к примеру с "1" объявленный в функции Map помнит эту "1"  и при следующем вызове, почему при втором вызове Map не новый, а старый?

```
function slow(x) {
  // здесь могут быть ресурсоёмкие вычисления
  alert(`Called with ${x}`);
  return x;
}

function cachingDecorator(func) {
  let cache = new Map();

  return function(x) {
    if (cache.has(x)) {    // если кеш содержит такой x,
      return cache.get(x); // читаем из него результат
    }

    let result = func(x); // иначе, вызываем функцию

    cache.set(x, result); // и кешируем (запоминаем) результат
    return result;
  };
}

slow = cachingDecorator(slow);

alert( slow(1) ); // slow(1) кешируем
alert( "Again: " + slow(1) ); // возвращаем из кеша

alert( slow(2) ); // slow(2) кешируем
alert( "Again: " + slow(2) ); // возвращаем из кеша
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: читайте что такое замыкание и область видимости и как оно работает.